# Call functions in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 10 functions which has to be called in a loop...

But if the user gives input 5, first 5 functions should be called.

If user gives 11 , after calling the 10 functions , it should start calling the rest 1 from the Beginning

I wrote the all the 10 functions, but I don't know how to achieve this.

```
def function_one():
    print("This is the first function")


def function_second():
    print("This is the second function")

.....
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put your functions into a list:

```
functions = [function_one, function_two, function_three, ...]
```

And loop over them:

```
n = int(input('Number: '))
for i in range(n):
    functions[i]()
```

Now what comes to your requirement:

> If user gives 11 , after calling the 10 functions , it should start calling the rest 1 from the Beginning

There are many ways to do this, but if we want to stick to the above code, we can just use the modulo operator (`%`) to allow "going past" the end:

```
n = int(input('Number: '))
for i in range(n):
    functions[i % len(functions)]()
```

You could also change the approach completely and use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) instead of looping over the list's indexes, and use the built-in [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get the functions:

```
import itertools

functions = [function_one, function_two, function_three, ...]
functions_it = itertools.cycle(functions)

n = int(input('Number: '))
for i in range(n):
    next(functions_it)()
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your functions in a list, then cycle through the list using the modulus operator, where N is the number of functions you are supposed to call:

```
functions = [function_one, function_two, function_three, ..., function_ten]
num_of_funcs = len(functions)

for i in range(N):
    functions[i % num_of_funcs]()
```

`i % num_of_funcs` will ensure that you start with the first function and wrap around to the first function again once you've hit the last function in the list.